# Usage of the w3c media fragment with images

Tags: html, image, httprequest, w3c

I am looking into responsively loading images for a web page (yes hot topic) I have chosen to use a srcset polyfill to take into account a dpi along with screen widths... The problem is I am choosing to use the image as a background for covering the entire screen (so I would need muliple different crops of the same image to be displayed for even just landscape vs. portrait views and doing this to fit multiple device widths and heights seems like a nightmare) So I am exploring different possibilities on how I can display and Image across multiple screen ratios and resolutions while still not loading massive Images just to only display say a third of it as rest is cropped out in order to not distort. I came across the w3c spec. for Media Fragments which basically allows for the retrieval of certain portion of a jpeg or video in pixel-ed, rectangular dimensions ie. 50% width and height of an image centered horizontally and vertically within an image. here's the link to the w3c spec --> [w3c link](http://www.w3.org/TR/media-frags/#fragment-dimensions) <-- explaining how to implement this for browser's now my question is with how the http request work do they fetch the entire image and crop client side or is there something the jpeg file format mapping bits of data to pixel locations which can be interpreted and parsed by the server to only return the specific bytes for the portion of the image I requested thus reducing the total number of bytes needed to serve the image?
 The reason I am asking is if so using media-fragmentation would allow me to dynamically crop any image to fit screen dimensions and additionally prevent additional bandwidth overhead needed to download an entire image when only half or third of pixels could be displayed. Anyways can anyone give me some insight into this? and which if any browser nativly support media fragmentation at this time (though this [polyfill](https://github.com/tomayac/xywh.js) seems to cover others )
Any insight into the inner-working would be greatly appreciaed I have briefed over the specs but can't quite seem to get the actual way download is pocessed with respect to images

Answer (score 0):

"can be interpreted and parsed by the server to only return the specific bytes for the portion of the image I requested"

AFAIK most media fragment players are just getting the entire resource from the server. There are media fragment server implementations but these are mainly demonstrative, one is Ninsuna Media Delivery (http://ninsuna.elis.ugent.be/ModelDrivenMediaDelivery)

"which if any browser nativly support media fragmentation at this time"

Firefox since version 9, Safari since Jan 2012 and Chrome since Jan 2012 (at least partially)

Credits to Raphael Troncy for this information I am reporting, from the MediaMixer project. There is a list of media fragment supporting software at http://community.mediamixer.eu/materials/software.